# error operators == cannot be applied search array?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, class, search

this probably will be confusing or messy but I need help with my program
this is my program:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int itemCountInteger;

    public struct Patient
    {
        public string patientidstring;
        public string firstNameString;
        public string lastNameString;


    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


    public class Patientn
    {
        private int patientId;
        public string firstName;
        private string lastName;

        public Patientn()
        {
            patientId = 0;
            firstName = "";
            lastName = "";
        }

        public Patientn(int idValue, string firstNameVal, string lastNameVal)
        {
            patientId = idValue;
            firstName = firstNameVal;
            lastName = lastNameVal;
        }

    }
```

I want to be able to use a patient class instead of a struct to add patients and for the search code bellow I get the error "operators == cannot be applied" i want to be able to search the array if the text in textbox matches a name in array if so display surname help?

```
    //Array
    Patient[] patientInfo = new Patient[10];

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (Patient patientinfoIndex in patientInfo)

            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidstring = textBox1.Text;
            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString = textBox2.Text;
            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString = textBox3.Text;

            string names = patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString + " " + patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString;
            listBox1.Items.Add(names);
            itemCountInteger++;
            listBox1.SelectedItem = names;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Contacts are limited to 20. Please delete some contacts prior to adding more.");
        }

    }


    //Search Button search a patients name and display his surname in the label if patient is found  display his surname
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int intTest = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < patientInfo.Length; x++)
        {
            if (textBox4.Text == patientInfo[x])
            {
                label6.Text =("surname");
                intTest = 1;
            }

        }

        if (intTest == 0)
        {
            label6.Text = ("not found");
        }
    }
```

I'm new to all of this sorry for asking and thanks in advance if you can help me with anything.

Comment: Please tell us where the error is.

Comment: Can you explain in human language how can string be equal to struct Patient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because of this line; `textBox4.Text == patientInfo[x]`. There are a few problems here but firstly, `textBox4.Text` is a string and you're trying to do an equality comparison with a `Patient` the compiler is saying there is no `==` operator defined for that. You can overload the `==` operator for `Patient` but this would only allow you to compare one instance of type `Patient` to another, never will you be able to compare a `Patient` to a `string` unless you cast both to type `object` in which case it's just going to do a reference comparison (not what you want).

I'm not sure which property in `Patient` you want to use here but I do know you need to compare `textBox4.Text` to one of the strings within the `Patient` class. Something like this would work; `(textBox4.Text == patientInfo[x].lastName)`

Comment: thanks it worked, you have any suggestion on how to get rid of the struct patient and use the class patientn instead?

Comment: @user3439080 yeah, where you declare `public struct patient` just make it `public class patient` I think the only functional difference (there are other differences but this is not the place to get intot that) will be that if you don't specify public/private the default is private for classes while it's public for structs.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to compare `System.String`--the type returned by `textBox4.Text`--to a `Patientn` instance. You probably mean to compare `Text` to `patientInfo[x].lastNameString`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do

```
textBox4.Text == patientInfo[x]
```

`patientInfo` contains instances of `Patience` and `textBox4.Text`is a `string`. There is no possible comparison between those two and that's why you get the error.

You're probably trying to do something like this

```
textBox4.Text == patientInfo[x].patientidstring
```